# Tracing sorting algorithms

Tags: python-3.x, selection-sort

I am trying to trace the changes in selection sort algorithm with python, Here's a piece of my code and what I've tried, the problem I am facing is printing the results in a table-like format

```
l = [2,5,1,7,9,5,3,0,-1]
iterat = 1
print('Iteration' + '\t\t\t' + 'Results')
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    val_to_sort = l[i]
    while l[i-1] > val_to_sort and i > 0:
        l[i-1], l[i] = l[i], l[i-1]
        i -= 1
        print(iterat, '\t\t\t', l[0:iterat + 1],'|',l[iterat:])
        iten += 1
```

from the code above, I am obtaining the following results:

[image]

But I am trying to obtain such results

[image: results I am trying to obtain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unident `print` one level to the left, so it is inside the `for` block instead of the `while` block.
- Use `join` and `map` to print the lists as a string
- You can use `enumerate` instead of manually incrementing `iterat`

```
def format_list(l):
    return ' '.join(map(str, l))

l = [2,5,1,7,9,5,3,0,-1]
print('Iteration' + '\t\t\t' + 'Results')

for iterat, i in enumerate(range(1, len(l)), 1):
    val_to_sort = l[i]
    while l[i-1] > val_to_sort and i > 0:
        l[i-1], l[i] = l[i], l[i-1]
        i -= 1
    print(iterat, '\t\t\t', format_list(l[0:iterat + 1]),'|', format_list(l[iterat:]))
```

Outputs

```
Iteration           Results
1            2 5 | 5 1 7 9 5 3 0 -1
2            1 2 5 | 5 7 9 5 3 0 -1
3            1 2 5 7 | 7 9 5 3 0 -1
4            1 2 5 7 9 | 9 5 3 0 -1
5            1 2 5 5 7 9 | 9 3 0 -1
6            1 2 3 5 5 7 9 | 9 0 -1
7            0 1 2 3 5 5 7 9 | 9 -1
8            -1 0 1 2 3 5 5 7 9 | 9
```

I can't help you with the Cyrillic text though ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am still trying to figure out iterators work.

Comment: just learnt a lot from enumerate, they are really helpful.|
Is there a way of getting rid of the last digit?